# BoundsChecker shows incorrect memory leak message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, bounds-checker

I'm using BoundsChecker9.1 with visual c++. I have a class

```
class Sample{
public:
vector<AnotherClass> x;
};
```

When I run my program the BoundsChecker tool reports all push_back() calls such as S.x.push_back(AnotherClass()) as memory leak.. Wouldn't all the elements in vector x will always be deallocated when the Sample class goes out of scope? If so, any idea about why BoundsChecker is showing them as memory leak? And I verified that "AnotherClass" doesnt have any memory leak either!!

Comment: Boundschecker rarely gets it wrong...

Comment: Do not format your code with HTML - use the 1010 button above the text input area

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: are you a philosopher?

Comment: @Ptabhu The leak, if there is one, may well be in AnotherClass.

Comment: Boundschecker (at least in previous versions, and I do not expect any difference) intercepts all memory allocs/deallocs. If it reports a leak, there is a very high probability that you have a leak.

Answer (score 4):

If the constructor of `AnotherClass` allocates memory which isn't deallocated in `~AnotherClass` you will have a memory leak.